# Ruby on Rails anchors/links during development problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may not be a big problem but I find this one as irritating. I wasn't able to figure it out. I have anchors in my site using link_to and even normal  tags. Example:

`<a href="#">Demo</a>`
will show up as Demo(#)

`<a href="/authenticate/">Authenticate</a>` would show up as Authenticate (/authenticate)

But if I view the source from the browser, I can't see a problem.

Does anybody know about this problem? I am using Rails 3 and a MAC.

Thank you,
Junrey

Comment: Possibly your browser doing something? Post the `link_to` code you're using and the source generated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a browser problem. I have tried safari, chrome and firefox, all doing the same thing. Even a simple `<a href="#">Test</a>` will show up as `Test (#)` in the browser display.

Comment: What do you mean by "show up as" Demo(#) or Authenticate(/authenticate)?  Please post your link_to snippets in erb, and what they look like when you view source in the browser, and we should be able to figure it out :)

Comment: Here is a screenshot to this problem: http://www.flickr.com/photos/webgeekph/5102264221/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my problem and it has something to do with the Blueprint CSS Framework that I am using.

I need to remove this `content: " (" attr(href) ") ";` from print.css which shows something like this:

`a:link:after, a:visited:after { content: " (" attr(href) ") "; font-size: 90%; }`

Found the solution from Ruby-Forum (http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206645#935056).